# Cycle Plugin slideshow not executed but images shown above each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I fire off this Ajax request to the server:

```
var xhr;
xhr = $.ajax({
url: "selectedPictures.php",
type: "POST",
data: {data: selectedPictures},
cache: false,
success: function(){
document.getElementById('loadHere').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
} });
```

selectedPictures being an integer array. Server side I check for the respective pictures and echo them with:

```
 echo "<img u=\"image\" src=\"".$picinfo['dirname']."/".$picinfo['basename']."\" width=\"960\" height=\"540\" /><br>";
```

The output for a selection of 3,4,5 in the xhr.response is:

```
<img u="image" src="img/Folie3.jpg" width="960" height="540" /><br>
<img u="image" src="img/Folie4.jpg" width="960" height="540" /><br>
<img u="image" src="img/Folie5.jpg" width="960" height="540" /><br>
```

being exactly what I want. When I post the output directly in the Cycle div:

```
<div id="loadHere" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=tileSlide></div>
```

it works fine, however when I get the server response in the script, the pictures are shown above one another and there are no slideshow effects.
I don't think it is a Cycle Plugin issue but rather a DOM/page loading/... issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html shows that there is a destroy command. So just destroy the cycle and recreate it.

Try something like…

```
success: function(imgs){
    $("#loadHere").cycle("destroy").html(imgs).cycle()
}
```

Comment: $("#loadHere").cycle("destroy").cycle(); worked fine, thank you!